# Youtube-ios-player-helper Cocoa error 258 in ios

Tags: ios, youtube-api

Received error rendering template:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)"
```

Comment: Please check in google before you post your question. There are many solutions available for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need copy Assets/YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html to main bundle to fix this issue.
It is available in below link.

https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/tree/master/Assets

more details about integration of youtube in ios see below link.

[Integration of youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)